# Cant pass value in php with pie graph

Tags: php, session-variables, pie-chart

I have a `page1.php` with image `scr="pieGraph.php"` inside it. And in my `pieGraph.php` i have a code like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['test']))
{
  $_SESSION['test'] = $_SESSION['test'];
}
else
{ 
  $_SESSION['test'] = 0;
}

$val1 = $_SESSION['test'];
$val2 = 30;
$val3 = 40;
$val4 = 50;
$val5 = 10;
 /* CAT:Pie charts */ 

 /* pChart library inclusions */ 
 include("chart/class/pData.class.php"); 
 include("chart/class/pDraw.class.php"); 
 include("chart/class/pPie.class.php"); 
 include("chart/class/pImage.class.php"); 

 /* Create and populate the pData object */ 
 $MyData = new pData();    
 $MyData->addPoints(array($val1,$val2,$val3,$val4,$val5),"ScoreA");   
 $MyData->setSerieDescription("ScoreA","Application A"); 

 /* Render the picture (choose the best way) */ 
$myPicture->autoOutput("pictures/example.draw2DRingValue.png"); 
?>
```

But session in this page doesn't work. Dont know why. Please help guys.

Comment: doesn't work? what do you mean? Is it always `0`? Where are you setting a new value?

Comment: if you're using `cookie-based` sessions, then your `session_start()` should be called before outputting anything. To solve the problem move it from `pieGraph.php` to top of the `page1.php`.

Comment: There's a submit button in my page1.php that triggers in collecting data from my database into table's data via jquery and when all the table data are already filled the pieGraph image must show each categories (there area 5) according to the data collected from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys :)) I already solved my problem :))) Thanks for this link [how to retrieve data from field name and column to generate graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058836/how-to-retrieve-data-from-field-name-and-column-to-generate-graph?rq=1)

So far this was my code:

```
 <?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
session_start();
include ("inc/dbcon.php"); 

if(isset($_SESSION['campaign']))
{
    $_SESSION['campaign'] = $_SESSION['campaign'];
}
else
{
$_SESSION['camapign'] = 'CEBU PACIFIC';
} 
if(isset($_SESSION['team']))
{
$_SESSION['team'] = $_SESSION['team'];
}
else
{
$_SESSION['team'] = 'TEAM AENNAH';
} 
if(isset($_SESSION['date']))
{
$_SESSION['date'] = $_SESSION['date'];
}
else
{
$_SESSION['date'] = "1999-01-01";
} 

$val1 = 100;
$val2 = 30;
$val3 = 40;
$val4 = 50;
$val5 = 10;
 /* CAT:Pie charts */ 

/* pChart library inclusions */ 
include("chart/class/pData.class.php"); 
include("chart/class/pDraw.class.php"); 
include("chart/class/pPie.class.php"); 
include("chart/class/pImage.class.php"); 

/* Create and populate the pData object */ 
$MyData = new pData();    
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_projected WHERE          fd_campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' AND fd_team='$_SESSION[team]' AND   fd_date='$_SESSION[date]'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
{   
$MyData->addPoints(array($val1,$val2,$val3,$val4,$val5),"ScoreA");   
$MyData->setSerieDescription("ScoreA","Application A");
}
else 
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$MyData->addPoints(array($row['fd_Bill_Calling_hrs'], $row['fd_Bill_Training_hrs'],    $row['fd_Bill_Support_hrs'], $row['fd_Bill_OT_hrs'], $row['fd_Bill_HO_OT_hrs'])); 
$MyData->setSerieDescription("ScoreA","Application A"); 
}
 }
```

Hope this will help others too :))